# ScrollTop работает некорректно

Tags: html, jquery, css

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        if($(document).scrollTop() > 500){
            $(".fading").animate({opacity:1},2000);
        }
    });
```

Когда прокручиваю страницу, то animate не запускается. Но стоит обновить страницу на отметке в 500px и ниже, как скрипт начинает работу. Как сделать, чтобы скрипт включался именно при скроле?

Comment: Потому что функция срабатывает только при загрузке страницы. Замени на $(window).scroll(...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы, вероятно, хотели проверять это на событие прокрутки, а не только в `$(document).ready`.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    if($(document).scrollTop() > 500){
        $(".fading").animate({opacity:1},2000);
    }
  });
  $(window).scroll();
});
```